# Facet a multivalue field (Solr powered Tag Cloud pt II)

Tags: solr, tag-cloud, facet

This is related to this: [Solr powered Tag Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737286/solr-powered-tag-cloud)
However i decided to create another question since it's different from the original scope of the first question.
Here's the deal, I ve managed to index a multivalued field with multiple words for a tag cloud:

```
    <arr name="words">
<str>builders_NNS</str>
<str>builders_NNS</str>
<str>buildings_NNS</str>
<str>buildings_NNS</str>
<str>construction_NN</str>
<str>construction_NN</str>
<str>green_JJ</str>
<str>green_JJ</str>
</arr>
```

But when I facet on the query with simple parameters: 
**&facet=true&facet.field=words&facet.mincount=1**

It fails to facet them correctly, it doesn't sum up the values... Do i need to send another extra parameter since it's a multivalued field? Response from Solr once i apply the faceting:

```
<lst name="facet_counts">
<lst name="facet_queries"/>
<lst name="facet_fields">
<lst name="words">
<int name="builders_NNS">1</int>
<int name="buildings_NNS">1</int>
<int name="construction_NN">1</int>
<int name="green_JJ">1</int>
</lst>
</lst>
</lst>
```

My field is defined as follows:

```
<field name="words" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
```

And i'm using Solr 1.4, Thanks!

Comment: same issue I have,....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question in here:
Solr is not capable (at least version 1.4, I haven't migrated to 3.2 yet and see if it's possible) to facet multivalued fields that are repeated in the same document, however it correctly groups repeated valued from different multivalued fields. Therefore the approach I was taking isn't possible (just yet).

Comment: And it should not be in my opinion. Since I'm using facetting over multivalued fields in my application, too, but wanting to have the 'document' counts not word counts, the current behavior seems to be the right one. If such an additional function should be available, it should be exactly that: additional