# SOLR related phrase search

Tags: java, solr

I'm indexing user comments related with an entity by entity id. Example of comments schema:

```
<fields>
   <field name="entity_id" type="sint" indexed="true" stored="true" default=0/>
   <field name="comment_id" type="sint" indexed="true" stored="true" default=0/>
   <field name="comment_text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true" default=""/>
</fields>
```

Now, I want to be able to query all comments for specific entity, and get the phrases which repeated several times in the set of comments.

Example of comments:

- This is **great place**
- You should really visit XYZ. **Great *place*** to bee.
- If you want to spend awesome moments, this is the *place to bee*.
- Great people and **great place**.

As you can see in example above, **Great place** is repeated several times, and also, *place to bee*. I need this phrases returned from SOLR, and I've tried with SOLR Facets, but I managed to get only words, not phrases ([Building a tag cloud with solr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7318326/building-a-tag-cloud-with-solr)).

Query I was trying with was kind of this:

```
http://localhost:8984/solr/select/?qt=tvrh&q=entity_id:12345&start=0&rows=0&facet=true&facet.field=comment_text&facet.minCount=1&facet.limit=50
```

Results were...

```
<lst name="facet_counts">
  <lst name="facet_queries"/>
  <lst name="facet_fields">
  <lst name="comment_text">
    <int name="epic">22</int>
    <int name="bar">18</int>
    <int name="you">16</int>
    <int name="quiver">15</int>
    <int name="happi">14</int>
    <int name="your">14</int>
    <int name="hour">13</int>
    <int name="drink">12</int>
    <int name="come">11</int>
    <int name="get">11</int>
    <int name="free">9</int> ...
```

*Note: these results are not related with example comments posted earlier :).*

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at using the [ShingleFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.ShingleFilterFactory)?  With this filter, you can combine tokens into phrases for indexing.  You could create a field that is just a copy of comment_text, use this filter on the field, and then get facets from that field

Comment: Great idea, I will certainly try it :)

Comment: Now I have problem when trying to search comments for different entity, I've got results from previous searches?! Can I remove it somehow and persist only with the entity related comments?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, can you give some examples.  Are you using a filter query to make sure that you only get back relevant data?